# Regular expression for a positive decimal comma separator with 2 decimal places MVC

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

Valid values for a Model property validation in a MVC5 project:

Decimal numbers from 0,01 to 999,99 but i can accept 0,1 or 9 or 9,01

```
0,01

,1

,20

1

1,2

1,20

00,2

00,20
```

For now I have:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(.\d+)?$", ErrorMessage = "Largura inválida.")]
```

But it accepts "." and more than 2 decimal places.

Comment: What is the question, what is the problem? What is the code you've tried to solve your problem

Comment: Hi thanks, I have edited the question.

Comment: hi @WiktorStribiżew thanks but it's accepting more then 2 decimal places

Comment: I am not sure if the decimal separator is `.`. Is it? And you also have a `,` as a digit grouping symbol? If yes, try `^[0-9]{0,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:[.][0-9]{1,2})?$`. However, this one seems to work for the input you provided: [`^[0-9]{0,3}(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:[.,][0-9]{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/tO1hF8/1)

Comment: I want numbers from 0,01 to 999,99 but i can accept 0,1 or 9 or 9,01

Comment: Do you mean you want to allow a specific range of float values from `0` to `999.99`? [`^([0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{1,2})?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/tO1hF8/2)? This one includes plain `0`. Do you want to exclude it?

Comment: Sorry I think I made a small mistake, I have to start from 0,01 and not from 0 :S

Comment: Should be as simple as `^[0-9]?[0-9]?\,?[0-9]?[0-9]?$`

Comment: hi @Icemanind thanks but it's accepting 0, sorry I have to start from 0,01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!0?(,0?0)?$)([0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{1,2})?)?$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA7zN3/4)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!0?(,0?0)?$)` - a negative lookahead forbidding the string to equal `0`, `0,0`, `0,00` or **even** `,0`
- `([0-9]{0,3}(,[0-9]{1,2})?)?` - optional group (matches one or zero times due to `?` at the end) matching

  - `[0-9]{0,3}` - zerot o three any digits
  - `(,[0-9]{1,2})?` - optionally matches a group of a comma, followed with 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Great! Thanks, I have made some testing and I think it's working. I had to find this regex to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882732/validate-number-with-globalize-or-with-dataannotation-in-mvc I don't know how but Globalize his giving me problems now with the "," separator.

Comment: Use `[,.]` to use both instead of `,`.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your comment

Comment: I do not understand what problem you have with the separator :) `^(?!0?([,.]0?0)?$)([0-9]{0,3}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?)?$` will match even if the decimal separator can be mixed.

Comment: yes but here in Portugal the separator for decimal values is "," so when I use Globalize with the "pt-PT" culture, I get the "The field XXXX must be a number." error message from the jquery-validate-unobstrutive library :(

Comment: I believe it is out of scope of the current question.

Answer (score 0):

or use this pattern

```
^(?=.*[1-9])([0-9]{0,3}(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA7zN3/5)